# How to get all elements of entity a and only the first of entity b?

Tags: sql

Lets say that we have 2 SQL tables `EntityA` and `EntityB`. How would a SQL statement/query look like, if we wanted to retrieve all elements of `EntityA` with only the latest (which has the highest Id value) `EntityB` which belongs to `EntityA`?

One `EntityA` can have multiple `EntityB` and `EntityB` can have only one `EntityA`.

**SQL tables:**

```
EntityA
Id
Title

EntityB
Id
Name
EntityAId
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
Title, Name3
Title, Name3
Title, Name3
```

and not

```
Title, Name1, Name2, Name3
Title, Name1, Name2, Name3
Title, Name1, Name2, Name3
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific and give sample table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data (as formatted text please).

Comment: @JoSmo your expected outcome is very weird. Otherwise, I don't understand why you would end up with 3 rows in your "current" outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If Oracle is your RDBMS:

```
SELECT * from 
   ( SELECT EntityA.*, EntityB.whateveryouwant from EntityA, EntityB 
          WHERE EntityA.joincolumn=EntityB.joincolumn order by EntityB.somecolumn) 
   where rownum < 2
```

The value of B.somecolumn is defined by what you call first EntityB

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM A 
    WHERE A.B_ID IN 
        (SELECT B.ID FROM B 
            WHERE ROWNUM < 2 ORDER BY ASC B.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample tables and data, though I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way:

```
SELECT A.[Title], B.[Name] FROM EntityA A
LEFT JOIN EntityB B
ON (
  B.[ID] = (SELECT MAX([EntityB].[Id]) FROM EntityB WHERE EntityB.[EntityAId] = A.[ID]))
```

The inner select finds the record with the highest `ID` for the given `EntityAId`. The outer select combines the `Title` from `EntityA` with the `Name` of `EntityB` for that maximum `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this query is little bit better and can be enhanced to get intended Name from EntityB.

```
SELECT A.Title , MAXB.Name
  FROM EntityA A,
       (  SELECT B.EntityAId, MAX (B.Name) Name
            FROM EntityB B
        GROUP BY B.EntityAId) MAXB
 WHERE A.Id = MAXB.EntityAId;
```